# Difference between fari and farti

Tags: word-difference

I have seen people use both *fari* and *farti* for the verb "to do", so I'm asking whether they are the same, or whether they have different meanings.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you say that *farti* is being used for *to do*, my guess is that you are referring to a translation of the phrase “how do you do?” as “kiel vi fartas?”. In this case *farti* is only a translation of *to do* in the very specific sense of being in either a good or bad state. I think a closer translation in English of *farti* could be *to fare*, as in “how do you fare?” except that the Esperanto word doesn’t sound old-fashioned.

The word *fari* is much more common and is a better translation of the more general sense of *to do* (as well as *to make*). Also note that *fari* is transitive as in the general sense of *to do*, ie you *do something* (*fari ion*) whereas in the other sense you are just either *doing well* or *doing badly* (*fartas bone, fartas malbone*) with no object.